# Looping through tuple

Tags: python, oracle

Dears, Your kind support as I could not understand the issue here !!!

so, I'm connecting to the cx_Oracle to get data then i'm doing for loop to print the data as below

```
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(--------)
var = conn.cursor()
var.execute("my query")

for item in var:
    print(item)
```

results: 
what I' seeing after running the code above is this:

```
(121, 'some info')
(121, 'some info')
(125, 'some info')
(126, 'some info')
```

which are true in DB. My question when I say

```
item[0]
```

I only get the last index =  (126, 'some info')

so how can I access all them and print rows that i want ?

PLEASE HELP !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would probably be to add some condition to your loop when you’re printing each item.

So pretty much you would want a condition that only the ones you want to print meets and then have your code

```
print(item)
```

Be the body of the if statement 
And the if condition be whatever you want your condition to be

```
for item in var:
    if expression:
         print(item)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! can you give me code example please !.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually fetch the items you queried for

```py
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(--------)
var = conn.cursor()
var.execute("my query")

items = var.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Either can put some condition:
   tups = [(121, 'some info'),
   (122, 'some info'),
   (125, 'some info'),
   (126, 'some info')]

for t in tups:
    if t[0] == 122:
        print(t)

OR
2. If you want to access particular item, then better way is to convert it to dictionary and fetch through key like below:
tups = [(121, 'some info'),
(122, 'some info'),
(125, 'some info'),
(126, 'some info')]
dictionary = dict((x, y) for x, y in tups)
print(dictionary)
print(dictionary[122])